# Combining all cascade delete queries into singe one with doctrine in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

1 `Country` can have 0 or many `League` so it is a 1-N relationship as we all know by one. I also set cascade delete as well. My question is: it might sound ambiguous but is there a way of combining all DELETE queries (the ones that delete associated records in `League` table) into single when I delete a country?

The reason I'm asking because if there are 100 records in League table, that means 100 DELETE queries. Please look at the image below which is from Symfony profiler.

Thanks

[image]

**CLASSES**

```
class Country
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *  targetEntity="League",
     *  mappedBy="country",
     *  cascade={"persist", "remove"},
     *  orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     */
    protected $league;
}

class League
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *  targetEntity="Country",
     *  inversedBy="league"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *  name="country_id",
     *  referencedColumnName="id",
     *  onDelete="CASCADE",
     *  nullable=false
     * )
     */
    protected $country;
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

I'm preventing lazy load running a separate query against `League` otherwise you would see one more query in image above.

```
public function findOneById($id)
{
    return
        $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c, l')
        ->leftJoin('c.league', 'l')
        ->where('c.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleResult();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

I normally don't keep whole logic in controller but this is just for demonstration purposes.

```
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('FootballFrontendBundle:Country');

    $country = $repo->findOneById($id);
    if ($country instanceof Country) {
        $em->remove($country);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'll probably want to have a custom query in your repository to delete leagues for you.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#delete-queries